Cannot drag and drop items in ubuntu chrome
Cannot drag and drop from my download folder or any folder to Chrome  in ubuntu 22.04 on wayland but it works in Xorg Why? Is there any solution for it.

apparently dragging and dropping between Wayland and Xwayland apps doesn't work very well right now. Apparently there are some command line flags you can use when running Chrome to force it to use regular Wayland instead of Xwayland, which might make drag and drop work better. Specifically I saw --ozone-platform-hint=wayland --enable-features=WaylandWindowDecorations --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer listed, but I don't know if it will work for you. There are also some improvements to Drag&Drop for Wayland that will be coming eventually soon hopefully.

In chrome://flags search for "Preferred Ozone platform" and change it to "Auto" so it will auto-select Wayland if possible or will default to X11.
